# Looking for particular JS method to confirm radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a question about how to solve this issue I am having using client side JS validation.

This is an online ordering system I built, and have just finished implementing the ability for the admins/managers to split & part ship an order. When that action is selected, I have some JS that shows a pair of radio buttons next to each line item in the order with the option to "do nothing" or "split this item to backorder", which then creates a second order in the system, moves any selected items to it and marks it for backorder.

This all works perfectly, but the issue is when the admin/manager chooses to "split & backorder" but either:
A) chooses no items to split
B) Chooses all of the items on an order to split
C) Tries to split & backorder and order with only 1 line item (for validation purposes, this is the same as selecting all items)

Resulting in either the original or split order potentially having no items attached to it.

I want to perform a JS validation that basically stops the PHP post and displays an alert if either condition of no items or all items being selected to split & backorder.

I have looked at doing this with a JS .onclick function and using a loop with a variable to count up total items & items selected and compare, but the issue is making this dynamic enough on to work with each order as the form radio buttons names change with each order (done by PHP). In PHP I would just have expanded the array with a loop from the post but I don't even know where to begin with that in client side JS.

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I really did not know where to start with this one, and a friend offered to look at it with me who knows his way around JS alot more than I.

This is what we ended up implementing:

```
function validateAction() {
  var $productRows = $(".product-row");
  var $productsToSplit = [];
  $productRows.each(function(i) {
     var splitChecked = $('input[type=radio][value=1]:checked', $productRows[i]);
     if(splitChecked.length > 0) $productsToSplit.push(splitChecked[0]); 
  });
  //console.log($productsToSplit);

    switch($productsToSplit.length) {
        case 0:
            alert('No products have been selected to split & backorder. Please check your selection and try again.');
            event.preventDefault();
            break;
        case $productRows.length:
            alert('You cannot select all products in an order to split & backorder. Please check your selection and try again.');
            event.preventDefault();
            break;
    }
  //console.log($productsToSplit.length + " : " + $productRows.length);

};
```

We ended up adding the class "productRows" to the Div for each product row, so we could then grab the checked radio button element and do our validation. This is the HTML involved:

```
<div class="row product-row">
                <!-- Div to show checkbox when Split Order is selected --> 
                <div class= "flat-green splititemchkbox" style="display:none" id="splititemchkbox">
                    <input type="hidden" name="splitbackitem[<?= @$prod['id'];?>][id]" value=<?= @$prod['id'];?>>

                    <input type="radio" style="transform: scale(2)" name="splitbackitem[<?= @$prod['id'];?>][checked]" value="0" checked="checked">
                    <label style="margin: 1%">Do Nothing</label>
                    <input type="radio" style="transform: scale(2)" name="splitbackitem[<?= @$prod['id'];?>][checked]" value="1">
                    <label style="margin-left: 1%">Split Item to Backorder</label>
                </div>
```

Hope this helps someone else looking for similar solution!

Cheers